# Is there any way to detect whether an option was passed as a default?

Tags: python, docopt

I'm creating a command-line interface for my script. I'd like the user to be able to provide options either in the command-line itself, or in a configuration file.

Certain options have reasonable defaults. The logic I want is this:

- If the option is neither in the command line nor in the config file, use the default.
- If the option is in the config file only, or the command line only, use the option.
- If the option is in both the config file *and* the command line, the explicit command line takes precedence.

For example, here is my docstring:

```
"""Usage: my-script.py [options] <some_arg>

Options:
  -c --config=<file>       Configuration file, if it exists. 
                           [default: settings.yaml]
  -d --delay=<delay>       Delay before scraping each message, to avoid rate
                           limiting. Delays by a gaussian distribution with
                           average <delay> and standard deviation <delay>/2.
                           [default: 1]
"""
```

And so, without a `settings.yaml` I want:

```
$ python my-script.py foo        # delay is "1"
$ python my-script.py -d 5 foo   # delay is "5"
```

And with a `settings.yaml` of `delay: 10` I want:

```
$ python my-script.py foo        # delay is "10"
$ python my-script.py -d 5 foo   # delay is "5"
```

The issue I run into is that `docopt` just gives me either a `{"--delay": "1"}` or `{"--delay": "5"}`. I have no way of knowing whether it comes from a default. Further, **I want to specify the default in the docstring** - this is much nicer from the user's perspective.

Is there any good docopt-y, Pythonic way to accomplish this? I was thinking to check the parsed arguments against the default arguments, but then the user would not be able to override a config file argument with a command-line argument if it happens to match the argument value.

---

Here's how I'm loading the config file:

```
args = docopt(__doc__, version='Yahoo! Groups Backup-er 0.1',
              options_first=True)
cfg_args = {}
if args['--config'] != 'settings.yaml' and not os.path.exists(args['--config']):
    sys.exit("Specified config file '%s' does not exist." % args['--config'])

if os.path.exists(args['--config']):
    settings = yaml.load(open(args['--config']))
    command_line_args = args
    args = {}
    for key, val in settings.items():
        args['--%s' % key] = val
    args.update(command_line_args)
```

Comment: Are you loading the config file yourself, or is docopt somehow handling that for you?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I'm loading it myself.

Comment: Show us how you are loading it.  The code I mean.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: sorry, just updated it with the code it was actually using

Comment: With `argparse` (yes, I know this is a `docopt` question) the surest way of knowing whether the user specified the value or not is to leave the default as `None`, and use a `if args.delay is None:` test after parsing.  There's no way of specifying `None` in the command line (with normal types).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the syntax to check is:

```
args = docopt(__doc__)
if args["--flag"]:
  print "With --flag\n"
```

Please read [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/454621/how-to-use-docopt-to-parse-command-line-options) article for details.